# saving copy of netflix new website

Tags: authentication, copy, wget

I am trying to dig into Netflix 's new website. Firebug and such tools are helpful of course, but I'd like to really get in there and play with it. Can anyone suggest a way to get a local copy on my computer? Tried basic wget, but I only get the download page. Tried using a name:pass as part of the URL. Also tried combining a curl command in the terminal with Wget.

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the page using keyboard shortcut `CTRL + S` or click `Save page as...` from your browsers menu.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking for something a bit more robust that will pull down a full copy if the site including assets.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997179/saving-a-web-page-and-externally-linked-assets-as-an-independent-static-resource